# Choosing layout for a dialog at runtime

Tags: java, android, layout, dialog, runtime

I need to extend `DialogFragment` to create dialogs that take user input and store them to be manipulated by another class. There are around six different layouts that could need to be displayed depending on which option the user selects. Extending dialogfragment six times doesnt sit well with me as a devoted initiate into OOP. My question then is how could I pass a layout to the DialogFragment at runtime.

I have tried both creating a class variable and a getter method in AdvantageDialog both to no avail.

It's instantiated like this

```
    DialogFragment newFragment = new AdvantageDialog();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "add_advantage");
```

but then newFragment.inputScreen nor newFragment.setInputScreen(some int) can be accessed from outside (ie. "setInputScreen(int) is undefined for the type dialogfragment"). 
I guess it would work if I did AdvantageDialog aD = new AdvantageDialog and then aD.setInputScreen(some int) but then I wouldnt benefit from the DialogFragment handling lifecycle methods. Also as far as I can see also there are no methods in the API for setting the view, only possible to change the view container.

Please any idea how to do this or can you direct me to where exactly my understanding is lacking. It would be greatly appreciated.
Andy

Comment: You can give your Dialogs any layout you like. A very good guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: it is indeed a great guide and I have pored over it at length. Unfotunately it doesn't address my specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment has the `setArgument` and `getArgument` method. You can provide the layout id through the bundle that `seArgument` takes as parameter and `getArgument` returns, and use this id inside `onCreateView` to inflate the corresponding view's object

Comment: absolutely perfect. Thank you so much. for future reference setting the arguement looks like this   :                                          DialogFragment newFragment = new AdvantageDialog();
  Bundle layoutInBundle = new Bundle();
  layoutInBundle.putInt("layoutId", id);
  newFragment.setArguments(layoutInBundle);
  newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "add_advantage");                                                          sorry it seems i need 15 rep to upvote you :(